# why do I get a syntax error for prepared statement?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I have written a prepared statement but its giving a syntax error at ?. I am not able to understand whats wrong.It should pass a movie name and get the result as directors of that movie

```
stmt=getConnection().createStatement();
        String sql="SELECT directors FROM moviedata WHERE moviedata.title = ?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1,movieName);
        rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql);
```

You shouldn't pass the SQL `String` to `executeQuery()`, since the prepared statement already contains the SQL `String` with the `?` placeholder replaced by the value of `movieName`.

Use:

```
rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: in the examples I saw they were actually putting the sql in execute query,anyways its solved now :) @Eran

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in  using Preparedstatement >Because the prepared statement object holds the sql query. The why again unnecessarily passing Sql string to executequery() method.`PreparedStatement preparedstatement=conn.PrepareStatement(sql)`. This holds the sql query and when executequery() method is called The query is evaluated.